# Java error in decryption

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

I have two classes named encryption.java and decryption.java. I want encrypt a text file using the encrypt.java class and decrypt from decrypt.java class. I can encrypt the text file successfully, but not able to decrypt it in same way. Can anyone tell me why not?

This is encrypt.java:

```
 public class Encrypt{


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

   String FileName = "D:/ashok/normal.txt";
    String FileName1 = "D:/ashok/encrypted.txt";


    KeyGenerator KeyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    KeyGen.init(128);

    SecretKey SecKey = KeyGen.generateKey();

    Cipher AesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");



    byte[] cipherText = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(FileName));
    AesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, SecKey);
    byte[] byteCipherText = AesCipher.doFinal(cipherText);
    Files.write(Paths.get(FileName1), byteCipherText);
 }
```

This is my decrypt.java class:

```
 class decrypt{
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
   String FileName1 = "D:/ashok/encrypted.txt";
        String FileName2 = "D:/ashok/decrypted.txt";

        KeyGenerator KeyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        KeyGen.init(128);

        SecretKey SecKey = KeyGen.generateKey();

        Cipher AesCipher =  Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        byte[] cipherrText = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(FileName1));

        AesCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, SecKey);
        byte[] bytePlainText = AesCipher.doFinal(cipherrText);
        Files.write(Paths.get(FileName2), bytePlainText);  }}
```

and getting error when decrypt class runs, like this

```
 javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:811)
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:676)
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:313)
  at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2086)
  at decryption.main(decryption.java:79)
```

Comment: try this AES-256 implementation with `keystore` https://github.com/sufiyanghori/aes-256-java-bks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before anything, I think that you should read more about symmetric cryptography [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm). As you will note, one of the main features of symmetric cryptography is that they *same* key is used to encrypt and decrypt. In contrast, asymmetric cryptography (or Public key cryptography [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography)) uses a pair of keys: one to encrypt and the other one to decrypt.

Thus, your problem is that you should persist the `SecretKey SecKey`. For instance, you can persist the secret key in a separate file. To do this, you need (a) the byte array (the key), and (b) the algorithm. An example of how to do this on the *Encrypt* side could be:

```
    String serializedSecKey = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(masterSecretKey.getEncoded())) + ";" + masterSecretKey.getAlgorithm()
    storeToFile(filename, serializedSecKey);
```

The `Base64.encodeBase64()` is from `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;`. Note that I have added a delimiter between the *key* and its *algorithm* to facilitate the parsing.

Then, in your *Decrypt* side you could parse the file containing the information regarding the secret key. An example to reconstruct the key would be:

```
    String serializedSecKey = // obtain the string from the file
    String [] key = serializedSecKey.split(";");
    byte[] keyBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(key[0]);
    String algorithm = key[1];
    SecretKey secKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, algorithm);
```

And the obtained `secKey` would be able to decrypt your message.

Finally, note that this might not be the best way to *persist* a secret key. There are much better options such as *KeyStores* that make all this sharing much easier.

Answer (score 1):

You generate the key used for encryption using `SecretKey SecKey = KeyGen.generateKey()`, which is fine, but when you decrypt you try to use a new key, instead of the one you used to encrypt the text. You need to save your key so you can use it for decrypting.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store this `SecretKey SecKey = KeyGen.generateKey();` value and share it between Encrypt and Decrypt classes.
So basically you have to use the same SecKey on both encryption and decryption processes.

Comment: yeah i think i have used the same secKey in both classes right?else , can you please modify my codes with your answer please.

Comment: No because this SecretKey SecKey = KeyGen.generateKey(); is always creating new SecretKey. See this for help: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796042/aes-encryption-and-decryption-with-java?rq=1)