# how to convert Base64 to String in java (For pdf)

Tags: java, pdf

I want to convert pdf to `base64`,thene again convert `base64` to pdf.
For this I converted  my pdf to `base64`. And I am trying to convert Base64 to string usin java.But it gives wrong output.

**My source code**

```
 byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(encodedstr);
 OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(f);
 Document document = new Document();
 PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);
 document.open();
 document.add(new Paragraph(new String(decodedBytes)));
 document.close();
 file.close();
```

**Where encodedstr is**

```
 JVBERi0xLjUKMSAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9QYWdlcwovS2lkcyBbMyAwIFJdCi9Db3Vu dCAxPj4KZW5kb2JqCjMgMCBvYmoKPDwvVHlwZSAvUGFnZQovUGFyZW50IDEgMCBSCi9N ZWRpYUJveCBbMCAwIDU5NS4yOCA4NDEuODldCi9SZXNvdXJjZXMgMiAwIFIKL1JvdGF0 ZSAwCi9Db250ZW50cyA0IDAgUj4+CmVuZG9iago0IDAgb2JqCjw8L0xlbmd0aCA1Nzkx Pj4Kc3RyZWFtCkJUIC9GMSA5LjAwIFRmIEVUCjAgVHIKL0dTMCBncwowIFR3IDAgVGMg MTAwIFR6IDAgVEwgCkJUIC9GMSAxNC4wMCBUZiBFVApxIDAgMCAwIHJnIEJUIDMxLjE5 IDc5My43NSBUZCAoRWNvbm9teSBUcnVja2luZyBNYW5hZ2VtZW50KSBUaiBFVCBRCkJU IC9GMSAxMS4wMCBUZiBFVAowLjg3ODQzMTM3MjU0OTAxOTYgMC44Nzg0MzEzNzI1NDkw MTk2IDAuODc4NDMxMzcyNTQ5MDE5NiByZwowIDAgMCBSRwovR1MxIGdzCjAuMDAgdwow IGkgCltdIDAgZAozIE0KMjguMzUgNzgyLjM2IDExOS4wNiAtNDIuNTIgcmUgYgovR1My IGdzCnEgMCAwIDAgcmcgQlQgODYuMzUgNzcxLjk3IFRkICggKSBUaiBFVCBRCnEgMCAw IDAgcmcgQlQgNDYuNjIgNzU3LjgwIFRkIChEb2N1bWVudCBOYW1lKSBUaiBFVCBRCnEg MCAwIDAgcmcgQlQgODYuMzUgNzQzLjYzIFRkICggKSBUaiBFVCBRCjAgMCAwIFJHCi9H UzMgZ3MKMC4wMCB3CjAgaSAKW10gMCBkCjMgTQoxNDcuNDEgNzgyLjM2IDE0NC41NyAt NDIuNTIgcmUgYgovR1M0IGdzCnEgMCAwIDAgcmcgQlQgMjE4LjE2IDc3MS45NyBUZCAo ICkgVGogRVQgUQpxIDAgMCAwIHJnIEJUIDE4MC44NyA3NTcuODAgVGQgKERvY3VtZW50 IFR5cGUpIFRqIEVUIFEKcSAwIDAgMCByZyBCVCAyMTguMTYgNzQzLjYzIFRkICggKSBU aiBFVCBRCjAgMCAwIFJHCi9HUzUgZ3MKMC4wMCB3CjAgaSAKW10gMCBkCjMgTQoyOTEu OTcgNzgyLjM2IDExMC41NSAtNDIuNTIgcmUgYgovR1M2IGdzCnEgMCAwIDAgcmcgQlQg MzQ1LjcyIDc3MS45NyBUZCAoICkgVGogRVQgUQpxIDAgMCAwIHJnIEJUIDMwOS42NSA3 NTcuODAgVGQgKEV4cGlyYXRpb24gRGF0ZSkgVGogRVQgUQpxIDAgMCAwIHJnIEJUIDM0 NS43MiA3NDMuNjMgVGQgKCApIFRqIEVUIFEKMCAwIDAgUkcKL0dTNyBncwowLjAwIHcK MCBpIApbXSAwIGQKMyBNCjQwMi41MiA3ODIuMzYgMTAyLjA1IC00Mi41MiByZSBiCi9H UzggZ3MKcSAwIDAgMCByZyBCVCA0NTIuMDIgNzcxLjk3IFRkICggKSBUaiBFVCBRCnEg MCAwIDAgcmcgQlQgNDE5LjkyIDc1Ny44MCBUZCAoU3VibWl0dGVkIE9uKSBUaiBFVCBR CnEgMCAwIDAgcmcgQlQgNDUyLjAyIDc0My42MyBUZCAoICkgVGogRVQgUQowIDAgMCBS RwovR1M5IGdzCjAuMDAgdwowIGkgCltdIDAgZAozIE0KNTA0LjU3IDc4Mi4zNiA1My44 NiAtNDIuNTIgcmUgYgovR1MxMCBncwpxIDAgMCAwIHJnIEJUIDUyOS45NyA3NzEuOTcg VGQgKCApIFRqIEVUIFEKcSAwIDAgMCByZyBCVCA1MTYuNTIgNzU3LjgwIFRkIChKb2Ig SWQpIFRqIEVUIFEKcSAwIDAgMCByZyBCVCA1MjkuOTcgNzQzLjYzIFRkICggKSBUaiBF VCBRCjAgMCAwIFJHCi9HUzExIGdzCjAuMDAgdwowIGkgCltdIDAgZAozIE0KMjguMzUg NzM5Ljg0IDExOS4wNiAtMTQuMTcgcmUgUwovR1MxMiBncwpxIDAgMCAwIHJnIEJUIDMx LjE5IDcyOS40NSBUZCAoYWJjKSBUaiBFVCBRCjAgMCAwIFJHCi9HUzEzIGdzCjAuMDAg dwowIGkgCltdIDAgZAozIE0KMTQ3LjQxIDczOS44NCAxNDQuNTcgLTE0LjE3IHJlIFMK L0dTMTQgZ3MKcSAwIDAgMCByZyBCVCAxNTAuMjQgNzI5LjQ1IFRkIChUQUcpIFRqIEVU IFEKMCAwIDAgUkcKL0dTMTUgZ3MKMC4wMCB3CjAgaSAKW10gMCBkCjMgTQoyOTEuOTcg NzM5Ljg0IDExMC41NSAtMTQuMTcgcmUgUwovR1MxNiBncwpxIDAgMCAwIHJnIEJUIDI5 NC44MSA3MjkuNDUgVGQgKDA3LzA4LzIwMTYpIFRqIEVUIFEKMCAwIDAgUkcKL0dTMTcg Z3MKMC4wMCB3CjAgaSAKW10gMCBkCjMgTQo0MDIuNTIgNzM5Ljg0IDEwMi4wNSAtMTQu MTcgcmUgUwovR1MxOCBncwpxIDAgMCAwIHJnIEJUIDQwNS4zNiA3MjkuNDUgVGQgKDA4 LzEzLzIwMTUpIFRqIEVUIFEKMCAwIDAgUkcKL0dTMTkgZ3MKMC4wMCB3CjAgaSAKW10g MCBkCjMgTQo1MDQuNTcgNzM5Ljg0IDUzLjg2IC0xNC4xNyByZSBTCi9HUzIwIGdzCnEg MCAwIDAgcmcgQlQgNTA3LjQxIDcyOS40NSBUZCAoMSkgVGogRVQgUQoxIDEgMSByZwow IDAgMCBSRwovR1MyMSBncwowLjAwIHcKMCBpIApbXSAwIGQKMyBNCjI4LjM1IDcyNS42 NyAxMTkuMDYgLTE0LjE3IHJlIGIKL0dTMjIgZ3MKcSAwIDAgMCByZyBCVCAzMS4xOSA3 MTUuMjggVGQgKFJlY2VudCBjb3B5KSBUaiBFVCBRCjAgMCAwIFJHCi9HUzIzIGdzCjAu MDAgdwowIGkgCltdIDAgZAozIE0KMTQ3LjQxIDcyNS42NyAxNDQuNTcgLTE0LjE3IHJl IGIKL0dTMjQgZ3MKcSAwIDAgMCByZyBCVCAxNTAuMjQgNzE1LjI4IFRkIChNQ1ApIFRq IEVUIFEKMCAwIDAgUkcKL0dTMjUgZ3MKMC4wMCB3CjAgaSAKW10gMCBkCjMgTQoyOTEu OTcgNzI1LjY3IDExMC41NSAtMTQuMTcgcmUgYgovR1MyNiBncwowIDAgMCBSRwovR1My NyBncwowLjAwIHcKMCBpIApbXSAwIGQKMyBNCjQwMi41MiA3MjUuNjcgMTAyLjA1IC0x NC4xNyByZSBiCi9HUzI4IGdzCnEgMCAwIDAgcmcgQlQgNDA1LjM2IDcxNS4yOCBUZCAo MDgvMTMvMjAxNSkgVGogRVQgUQowIDAgMCBSRwovR1MyOSBncwowLjAwIHcKMCBpIApb XSAwIGQKMyBNCjUwNC41NyA3MjUuNjcgNTMuODYgLTE0LjE3IHJlIGIKL0dTMzAgZ3MK cSAwIDAgMCByZyBCVCA1MDcuNDEgNzE1LjI4IFRkICgxKSBUaiBFVCBRCjAgMCAwIFJH Ci9HUzMxIGdzCjAuMDAgdwowIGkgCltdIDAgZAozIE0KMjguMzUgNzExLjQ5IDExOS4w NiAtMTQuMTcgcmUgUwovR1MzMiBncwpxIDAgMCAwIHJnIEJUIDMxLjE5IDcwMS4xMSBU ZCAoZHIgY2VydGlmaWNhdGUpIFRqIEVUIFEKMCAwIDAgUkcKL0dTMzMgZ3MKMC4wMCB3 CjAgaSAKW10gMCBkCjMgTQoxNDcuNDEgNzExLjQ5IDE0NC41NyAtMTQuMTcgcmUgUwov R1MzNCBncwpxIDAgMCAwIHJnIEJUIDE1MC4yNCA3MDEuMTEgVGQgKERSVUcgQ0VSVElG SUNBVEUpIFRqIEVUIFEKMCAwIDAgUkcKL0dTMzUgZ3MKMC4wMCB3CjAgaSAKW10gMCBk CjMgTQoyOTEuOTcgNzExLjQ5IDExMC41NSAtMTQuMTcgcmUgUwovR1MzNiBncwpxIDAg MCAwIHJnIEJUIDI5NC44MSA3MDEuMTEgVGQgKDAyLzEwLzIwMTYpIFRqIEVUIFEKMCAw IDAgUkcKL0dTMzcgZ3MKMC4wMCB3CjAgaSAKW10gMCBkCjMgTQo0MDIuNTIgNzExLjQ5 IDEwMi4wNSAtMTQuMTcgcmUgUwovR1MzOCBncwpxIDAgMCAwIHJnIEJUIDQwNS4zNiA3 MDEuMTEgVGQgKDA3LzAzLzIwMTUpIFRqIEVUIFEKMCAwIDAgUkcKL0dTMzkgZ3MKMC4w MCB3CjAgaSAKW10gMCBkCjMgTQo1MDQuNTcgNzExLjQ5IDUzLjg2IC0xNC4xNyByZSBT Ci9HUzQwIGdzCnEgMCAwIDAgcmcgQlQgNTA3LjQxIDcwMS4xMSBUZCAoMSkgVGogRVQg UQoxIDEgMSByZwowIDAgMCBSRwovR1M0MSBncwowLjAwIHcKMCBpIApbXSAwIGQKMyBN CjI4LjM1IDY5Ny4zMiAxMTkuMDYgLTE0LjE3IHJlIGIKL0dTNDIgZ3MKcSAwIDAgMCBy ZyBCVCAzMS4xOSA2ODYuOTMgVGQgKExpY2VuY2UpIFRqIEVUIFEKMCAwIDAgUkcKL0dT NDMgZ3MKMC4wMCB3CjAgaSAKW10gMCBkCjMgTQoxNDcuNDEgNjk3LjMyIDE0NC41NyAt MTQuMTcgcmUgYgovR1M0NCBncwpxIDAgMCAwIHJnIEJUIDE1MC4yNCA2ODYuOTMgVGQg KERSSVZFUlMgTElDRU5TRSkgVGogRVQgUQowIDAgMCBSRwovR1M0NSBncwowLjAwIHcK MCBpIApbXSAwIGQKMyBNCjI5MS45NyA2OTcuMzIgMTEwLjU1IC0xNC4xNyByZSBiCi9H UzQ2IGdzCjAgMCAwIFJHCi9HUzQ3IGdzCjAuMDAgdwowIGkgCltdIDAgZAozIE0KNDAy LjUyIDY5Ny4zMiAxMDIuMDUgLTE0LjE3IHJlIGIKL0dTNDggZ3MKcSAwIDAgMCByZyBC VCA0MDUuMzYgNjg2LjkzIFRkICgwNy8wMy8yMDE1KSBUaiBFVCBRCjAgMCAwIFJHCi9H UzQ5IGdzCjAuMDAgdwowIGkgCltdIDAgZAozIE0KNTA0LjU3IDY5Ny4zMiA1My44NiAt MTQuMTcgcmUgYgovR1M1MCBncwpxIDAgMCAwIHJnIEJUIDUwNy40MSA2ODYuOTMgVGQg KDEpIFRqIEVUIFEKMCAwIDAgUkcKL0dTNTEgZ3MKMC4wMCB3CjAgaSAKW10gMCBkCjMg TQoyOC4zNSA2ODMuMTUgMTE5LjA2IC0xNC4xNyByZSBTCi9HUzUyIGdzCnEgMCAwIDAg cmcgQlQgMzEuMTkgNjcyLjc2IFRkICgxc3QpIFRqIEVUIFEKMCAwIDAgUkcKL0dTNTMg Z3MKMC4wMCB3CjAgaSAKW10gMCBkCjMgTQoxNDcuNDEgNjgzLjE1IDE0NC41NyAtMTQu MTcgcmUgUwovR1M1NCBncwpxIDAgMCAwIHJnIEJUIDE1MC4yNCA2NzIuNzYgVGQgKFRB RykgVGogRVQgUQowIDAgMCBSRwovR1M1NSBncwowLjAwIHcKMCBpIApbXSAwIGQKMyBN CjI5MS45NyA2ODMuMTUgMTEwLjU1IC0xNC4xNyByZSBTCi9HUzU2IGdzCnEgMCAwIDAg cmcgQlQgMjk0LjgxIDY3Mi43NiBUZCAoMDMvMjQvMjAxNikgVGogRVQgUQowIDAgMCBS RwovR1M1NyBncwowLjAwIHcKMCBpIApbXSAwIGQKMyBNCjQwMi41MiA2ODMuMTUgMTAy LjA1IC0xNC4xNyByZSBTCi9HUzU4IGdzCnEgMCAwIDAgcmcgQlQgNDA1LjM2IDY3Mi43 NiBUZCAoMDcvMDEvMjAxNSkgVGogRVQgUQowIDAgMCBSRwovR1M1OSBncwowLjAwIHcK MCBpIApbXSAwIGQKMyBNCjUwNC41NyA2ODMuMTUgNTMuODYgLTE0LjE3IHJlIFMKL0dT NjAgZ3MKcSAwIDAgMCByZyBCVCA1MDcuNDEgNjcyLjc2IFRkICgxKSBUaiBFVCBRCjEg MSAxIHJnCjAgMCAwIFJHCi9HUzYxIGdzCjAuMDAgdwowIGkgCltdIDAgZAozIE0KMjgu MzUgNjY4Ljk3IDExOS4wNiAtMTQuMTcgcmUgYgovR1M2MiBncwpxIDAgMCAwIHJnIEJU IDMxLjE5IDY1OC41OSBUZCAoMm5kKSBUaiBFVCBRCjAgMCAwIFJHCi9HUzYzIGdzCjAu MDAgdwowIGkgCltdIDAgZAozIE0KMTQ3LjQxIDY2OC45NyAxNDQuNTcgLTE0LjE3IHJl IGIKL0dTNjQgZ3MKcSAwIDAgMCByZyBCVCAxNTAuMjQgNjU4LjU5IFRkIChTQ0FMRSBU SUNLRVQpIFRqIEVUIFEKMCAwIDAgUkcKL0dTNjUgZ3MKMC4wMCB3CjAgaSAKW10gMCBk CjMgTQoyOTEuOTcgNjY4Ljk3IDExMC41NSAtMTQuMTcgcmUgYgovR1M2NiBncwpxIDAg MCAwIHJnIEJUIDI5NC44MSA2NTguNTkgVGQgKDA3LzIyLzIwMTUpIFRqIEVUIFEKMCAw IDAgUkcKL0dTNjcgZ3MKMC4wMCB3CjAgaSAKW10gMCBkCjMgTQo0MDIuNTIgNjY4Ljk3 IDEwMi4wNSAtMTQuMTcgcmUgYgovR1M2OCBncwpxIDAgMCAwIHJnIEJUIDQwNS4zNiA2 NTguNTkgVGQgKDA3LzAxLzIwMTUpIFRqIEVUIFEKMCAwIDAgUkcKL0dTNjkgZ3MKMC4w MCB3CjAgaSAKW10gMCBkCjMgTQo1MDQuNTcgNjY4Ljk3IDUzLjg2IC0xNC4xNyByZSBi Ci9HUzcwIGdzCnEgMCAwIDAgcmcgQlQgNTA3LjQxIDY1OC41OSBUZCAoMSkgVGogRVQg UQowIDAgMCBSRwovR1M3MSBncwowLjAwIHcKMCBpIApbXSAwIGQKMyBNCjI4LjM1IDY1 NC44MCAxMTkuMDYgLTE0LjE3IHJlIFMKL0dTNzIgZ3MKcSAwIDAgMCByZyBCVCAzMS4x OSA2NDQuNDEgVGQgKDNyZCkgVGogRVQgUQowIDAgMCBSRwovR1M3MyBncwowLjAwIHcK MCBpIApbXSAwIGQKMyBNCjE0Ny40MSA2NTQuODAgMTQ0LjU3IC0xNC4xNyByZSBTCi9H Uzc0IGdzCnEgMCAwIDAgcmcgQlQgMTUwLjI0IDY0NC40MSBUZCAoQklUKSBUaiBFVCBR CjAgMCAwIFJHCi9HUzc1IGdzCjAuMDAgdwowIGkgCltdIDAgZAozIE0KMjkxLjk3IDY1 NC44MCAxMTAuNTUgLTE0LjE3IHJlIFMKL0dTNzYgZ3MKMCAwIDAgUkcKL0dTNzcgZ3MK MC4wMCB3CjAgaSAKW10gMCBkCjMgTQo0MDIuNTIgNjU0LjgwIDEwMi4wNSAtMTQuMTcg cmUgUwovR1M3OCBncwpxIDAgMCAwIHJnIEJUIDQwNS4zNiA2NDQuNDEgVGQgKDA3LzAx LzIwMTUpIFRqIEVUIFEKMCAwIDAgUkcKL0dTNzkgZ3MKMC4wMCB3CjAgaSAKW10gMCBk CjMgTQo1MDQuNTcgNjU0LjgwIDUzLjg2IC0xNC4xNyByZSBTCi9HUzgwIGdzCnEgMCAw IDAgcmcgQlQgNTA3LjQxIDY0NC40MSBUZCAoMSkgVGogRVQgUQplbmRzdHJlYW0KZW5k b2JqCjUgMCBvYmoKPDwvVHlwZSAvT0NHIC9OYW1lIChwcmludCkKL1VzYWdlIDw8L1By aW50IDw8L1ByaW50U3RhdGUgL09OPj4gL1ZpZXcgPDwvVmlld1N0YXRlIC9PRkY+Pj4+ Pj4KZW5kb2JqCjYgMCBvYmoKPDwvVHlwZSAvT0NHIC9OYW1lICh2aWV3KQovVXNhZ2Ug PDwvUHJpbnQgPDwvUHJpbnRTdGF0ZSAvT0ZGPj4gL1ZpZXcgPDwvVmlld1N0YXRlIC9P Tj4+Pj4+PgplbmRvYmoKNyAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9FeHRHU3RhdGUKL0NBIDEKL2Nh IDEKL0JNIC9Ob3JtYWwKL24gNwovU0EgdHJ1ZQo+PgplbmRvYmoKOCAwIG9iago8PC9U eXBlIC9FeHRHU3RhdGUKL0NBIDAuMQovY2EgMC4xCi9CTSAvTm9ybWFsCi9uIDgKL1NB IHRydWUKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjkgMCBvYmoKPDwvVHlwZSAvRXh0R1N0YXRlCi9DQSAxCi9j YSAxCi9CTSAvTm9ybWFsCi9uIDkKL1NBIHRydWUKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjEwIDAgb2JqCjw8 L1R5cGUgL0V4dEdTdGF0ZQovQ0EgMC4xCi9jYSAwLjEKL0JNIC9Ob3JtYWwKL24gMTAK L1NBIHRydWUKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjExIDAgb2JqCjw8L1R5cGUgL0V4dEdTdGF0ZQovQ0Eg MQovY2EgMQovQk0gL05vcm1hbAovbiAxMQovU0EgdHJ1ZQo+PgplbmRvYmoKMTIgMCBv YmoKPDwvVHlwZSAvRXh0R1N0YXRlCi9DQSAwLjEKL2NhIDAuMQovQk0gL05vcm1hbAov biAxMgovU0EgdHJ1ZQo+PgplbmRvYmoKMTMgMCBvYmoKPDwvVHlwZSAvRXh0R1N0YXRl Ci9DQSAxCi9jYSAxCi9CTSAvTm9ybWFsCi9uIDEzCi9TQSB0cnVlCj4+CmVuZG9iagox NCAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9FeHRHU3RhdGUKL0NBIDAuMQovY2EgMC4xCi9CTSAvTm9y bWFsCi9uIDE0Ci9TQSB0cnVlCj4+CmVuZG9iagoxNSAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9FeHRH U3RhdGUKL0NBIDEKL2NhIDEKL0JNIC9Ob3JtYWwKL24gMTUKL1NBIHRydWUKPj4KZW5k b2JqCjE2IDAgb2JqCjw8L1R5cGUgL0V4dEdTdGF0ZQovQ0EgMC4xCi9jYSAwLjEKL0JN IC9Ob3JtYWwKL24gMTYKL1NBIHRydWUKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjE3IDAgb2JqCjw8L1R5cGUg L0V4dEdTdGF0ZQovQ0EgMQovY2EgMQovQk0gL05vcm1hbAovbiAxNwovU0EgdHJ1ZQo+ PgplbmRvYmoKMTggMCBvYmoKPDwvVHlwZSAvRXh0R1N0YXRlCi9DQSAwLjEKL2NhIDAu MQovQk0gL05vcm1hbAovbiAxOAovU0EgdHJ1ZQo+PgplbmRvYmoKMTkgMCBvYmoKPDwv VHlwZSAvRXh0R1N0YXRlCi9DQSAxCi9jYSAxCi9CTSAvTm9ybWFsCi9uIDE5Ci9TQSB0 cnVlCj4+CmVuZG9iagoyMCAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9FeHRHU3RhdGUKL0NBIDAuMQov Y2EgMC4xCi9CTSAvTm9ybWFsCi9uIDIwCi9TQSB0cnVlCj4+CmVuZG9iagoyMSAwIG9i ago8PC9UeXBlIC9FeHRHU3RhdGUKL0NBIDEKL2NhIDEKL0JNIC9Ob3JtYWwKL24gMjEK L1NBIHRydWUKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjIyIDAgb2JqCjw8L1R5cGUgL0V4dEdTdGF0ZQovQ0Eg MC4xCi9jYSAwLjEKL0JNIC9Ob3JtYWwKL24gMjIKL1NBIHRydWUKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjIz IDAgb2JqCjw8L1R5cGUgL0V4dEdTdGF0ZQovQ0EgMQovY2EgMQovQk0gL05vcm1hbAov biAyMwovU0EgdHJ1ZQo+PgplbmRvYmoKMjQgMCBvYmoKPDwvVHlwZSAvRXh0R1N0YXRl Ci9DQSAwLjEKL2NhIDAuMQovQk0gL05vcm1hbAovbiAyNAovU0EgdHJ1ZQo+PgplbmRv YmoKMjUgMCBvYmoKPDwvVHlwZSAvRXh0R1N0YXRlCi9DQSAxCi9jYSAxCi9CTSAvTm9y bWFsCi9uIDI1Ci9TQSB0cnVlCj4+CmVuZG9iagoyNiAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9FeHRH U3RhdGUKL0NBIDAuMQovY2EgMC4xCi9CTSAvTm9ybWFsCi9uIDI2Ci9TQSB0cnVlCj4+ CmVuZG9iagoyNyAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9FeHRHU3RhdGUKL0NBIDEKL2NhIDEKL0JN IC9Ob3JtYWwKL24gMjcKL1NBIHRydWUKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjI4IDAgb2JqCjw8L1R5cGUg L0V4dEdTdGF0ZQovQ0EgMC4xCi9jYSAwLjEKL0JNIC9Ob3JtYWwKL24gMjgKL1NBIHRy dWUKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjI5IDAgb2JqCjw8L1R5cGUgL0V4dEdTdGF0ZQovQ0EgMQovY2Eg MQovQk0gL05vcm1hbAovbiAyOQovU0EgdHJ1ZQo+PgplbmRvYmoKMzAgMCBvYmoKPDwv VHlwZSAvRXh0R1N0YXRlCi9DQSAwLjEKL2NhIDAuMQovQk0gL05vcm1hbAovbiAzMAov U0EgdHJ1ZQo+PgplbmRvYmoKMzEgMCBvYmoKPDwvVHlwZSAvRXh0R1N0YXRlCi9DQSAx Ci9jYSAxCi9CTSAvTm9ybWFsCi9uIDMxCi9TQSB0cnVlCj4+CmVuZG9iagozMiAwIG9i ago8PC9UeXBlIC9FeHRHU3RhdGUKL0NBIDAuMQovY2EgMC4xCi9CTSAvTm9ybWFsCi9u IDMyCi9TQSB0cnVlCj4+CmVuZG9iagozMyAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9FeHRHU3RhdGUK L0NBIDEKL2NhIDEKL0JNIC9Ob3JtYWwKL24gMzMKL1NBIHRydWUKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjM0 IDAgb2JqCjw8L1R5cGUgL0V4dEdTdGF0ZQovQ0EgMC4xCi9jYSAwLjEKL0JNIC9Ob3Jt YWwKL24gMzQKL1NBIHRydWUKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjM1IDAgb2JqCjw8L1R5cGUgL0V4dEdT dGF0ZQovQ0EgMQovY2EgMQovQk0gL05vcm1hbAovbiAzNQovU0EgdHJ1ZQo+PgplbmRv YmoKMzYgMCBvYmoKPDwvVHlwZSAvRXh0R1N0YXRlCi9DQSAwLjEKL2NhIDAuMQovQk0g L05vcm1hbAovbiAzNgovU0EgdHJ1ZQo+PgplbmRvYmoKMzcgMCBvYmoKPDwvVHlwZSAv RXh0R1N0YXRlCi9DQSAxCi9jYSAxCi9CTSAvTm9ybWFsCi9uIDM3Ci9TQSB0cnVlCj4+ CmVuZG9iagozOCAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9FeHRHU3RhdGUKL0NBIDAuMQovY2EgMC4x Ci9CTSAvTm9ybWFsCi9uIDM4Ci9TQSB0cnVlCj4+CmVuZG9iagozOSAwIG9iago8PC9U eXBlIC9FeHRHU3RhdGUKL0NBIDEKL2NhIDEKL0JNIC9Ob3JtYWwKL24gMzkKL1NBIHRy dWUKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjQwIDAgb2JqCjw8L1R5cGUgL0V4dEdTdGF0ZQovQ0EgMC4xCi9j YSAwLjEKL0JNIC9Ob3JtYWwKL24gNDAKL1NBIHRydWUKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjQxIDAgb2Jq Cjw8L1R5cGUgL0V4dEdTdGF0ZQovQ0EgMQovY2EgMQovQk0gL05vcm1hbAovbiA0MQov U0EgdHJ1ZQo+PgplbmRvYmoKNDIgMCBvYmoKPDwvVHlwZSAvRXh0R1N0YXRlCi9DQSAw LjEKL2NhIDAuMQovQk0gL05vcm1hbAovbiA0MgovU0EgdHJ1ZQo+PgplbmRvYmoKNDMg MCBvYmoKPDwvVHlwZSAvRXh0R1N0YXRlCi9DQSAxCi9jYSAxCi9CTSAvTm9ybWFsCi9u IDQzCi9TQSB0cnVlCj4+CmVuZG9iago0NCAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9FeHRHU3RhdGUK L0NBIDAuMQovY2EgMC4xCi9CTSAvTm9ybWFsCi9uIDQ0Ci9TQSB0cnVlCj4+CmVuZG9i ago0NSAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9FeHRHU3RhdGUKL0NBIDEKL2NhIDEKL0JNIC9Ob3Jt YWwKL24gNDUKL1NBIHRydWUKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjQ2IDAgb2JqCjw8L1R5cGUgL0V4dEdT dGF0ZQovQ0EgMC4xCi9jYSAwLjEKL0JNIC9Ob3JtYWwKL24gNDYKL1NBIHRydWUKPj4K ZW5kb2JqCjQ3IDAgb2JqCjw8L1R5cGUgL0V4dEdTdGF0ZQovQ0EgMQovY2EgMQovQk0g L05vcm1hbAovbiA0NwovU0EgdHJ1ZQo+PgplbmRvYmoKNDggMCBvYmoKPDwvVHlwZSAv RXh0R1N0YXRlCi9DQSAwLjEKL2NhIDAuMQovQk0gL05vcm1hbAovbiA0OAovU0EgdHJ1 ZQo+PgplbmRvYmoKNDkgMCBvYmoKPDwvVHlwZSAvRXh0R1N0YXRlCi9DQSAxCi9jYSAx Ci9CTSAvTm9ybWFsCi9uIDQ5Ci9TQSB0cnVlCj4+CmVuZG9iago1MCAwIG9iago8PC9U eXBlIC9FeHRHU3RhdGUKL0NBIDAuMQovY2EgMC4xCi9CTSAvTm9ybWFsCi9uIDUwCi9T QSB0cnVlCj4+CmVuZG9iago1MSAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9FeHRHU3RhdGUKL0NBIDEK L2NhIDEKL0JNIC9Ob3JtYWwKL24gNTEKL1NBIHRydWUKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjUyIDAgb2Jq Cjw8L1R5cGUgL0V4dEdTdGF0ZQovQ0EgMC4xCi9jYSAwLjEKL0JNIC9Ob3JtYWwKL24g NTIKL1NBIHRydWUKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjUzIDAgb2JqCjw8L1R5cGUgL0V4dEdTdGF0ZQov Q0EgMQovY2EgMQovQk0gL05vcm1hbAovbiA1MwovU0EgdHJ1ZQo+PgplbmRvYmoKNTQg MCBvYmoKPDwvVHlwZSAvRXh0R1N0YXRlCi9DQSAwLjEKL2NhIDAuMQovQk0gL05vcm1h bAovbiA1NAovU0EgdHJ1ZQo+PgplbmRvYmoKNTUgMCBvYmoKPDwvVHlwZSAvRXh0R1N0 YXRlCi9DQSAxCi9jYSAxCi9CTSAvTm9ybWFsCi9uIDU1Ci9TQSB0cnVlCj4+CmVuZG9i ago1NiAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9FeHRHU3RhdGUKL0NBIDAuMQovY2EgMC4xCi9CTSAv Tm9ybWFsCi9uIDU2Ci9TQSB0cnVlCj4+CmVuZG9iago1NyAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9F eHRHU3RhdGUKL0NBIDEKL2NhIDEKL0JNIC9Ob3JtYWwKL24gNTcKL1NBIHRydWUKPj4K ZW5kb2JqCjU4IDAgb2JqCjw8L1R5cGUgL0V4dEdTdGF0ZQovQ0EgMC4xCi9jYSAwLjEK L0JNIC9Ob3JtYWwKL24gNTgKL1NBIHRydWUKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjU5IDAgb2JqCjw8L1R5 cGUgL0V4dEdTdGF0ZQovQ0EgMQovY2EgMQovQk0gL05vcm1hbAovbiA1OQovU0EgdHJ1 ZQo+PgplbmRvYmoKNjAgMCBvYmoKPDwvVHlwZSAvRXh0R1N0YXRlCi9DQSAwLjEKL2Nh IDAuMQovQk0gL05vcm1hbAovbiA2MAovU0EgdHJ1ZQo+PgplbmRvYmoKNjEgMCBvYmoK PDwvVHlwZSAvRXh0R1N0YXRlCi9DQSAxCi9jYSAxCi9CTSAvTm9ybWFsCi9uIDYxCi9T QSB0cnVlCj4+CmVuZG9iago2MiAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9FeHRHU3RhdGUKL0NBIDAu MQovY2EgMC4xCi9CTSAvTm9ybWFsCi9uIDYyCi9TQSB0cnVlCj4+CmVuZG9iago2MyAw IG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9FeHRHU3RhdGUKL0NBIDEKL2NhIDEKL0JNIC9Ob3JtYWwKL24g NjMKL1NBIHRydWUKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjY0IDAgb2JqCjw8L1R5cGUgL0V4dEdTdGF0ZQov Q0EgMC4xCi9jYSAwLjEKL0JNIC9Ob3JtYWwKL24gNjQKL1NBIHRydWUKPj4KZW5kb2Jq CjY1IDAgb2JqCjw8L1R5cGUgL0V4dEdTdGF0ZQovQ0EgMQovY2EgMQovQk0gL05vcm1h bAovbiA2NQovU0EgdHJ1ZQo+PgplbmRvYmoKNjYgMCBvYmoKPDwvVHlwZSAvRXh0R1N0 YXRlCi9DQSAwLjEKL2NhIDAuMQovQk0gL05vcm1hbAovbiA2NgovU0EgdHJ1ZQo+Pgpl bmRvYmoKNjcgMCBvYmoKPDwvVHlwZSAvRXh0R1N0YXRlCi9DQSAxCi9jYSAxCi9CTSAv Tm9ybWFsCi9uIDY3Ci9TQSB0cnVlCj4+CmVuZG9iago2OCAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9F eHRHU3RhdGUKL0NBIDAuMQovY2EgMC4xCi9CTSAvTm9ybWFsCi9uIDY4Ci9TQSB0cnVl Cj4+CmVuZG9iago2OSAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9FeHRHU3RhdGUKL0NBIDEKL2NhIDEK L0JNIC9Ob3JtYWwKL24gNjkKL1NBIHRydWUKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjcwIDAgb2JqCjw8L1R5 cGUgL0V4dEdTdGF0ZQovQ0EgMC4xCi9jYSAwLjEKL0JNIC9Ob3JtYWwKL24gNzAKL1NB IHRydWUKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjcxIDAgb2JqCjw8L1R5cGUgL0V4dEdTdGF0ZQovQ0EgMQov Y2EgMQovQk0gL05vcm1hbAovbiA3MQovU0EgdHJ1ZQo+PgplbmRvYmoKNzIgMCBvYmoK PDwvVHlwZSAvRXh0R1N0YXRlCi9DQSAwLjEKL2NhIDAuMQovQk0gL05vcm1hbAovbiA3 MgovU0EgdHJ1ZQo+PgplbmRvYmoKNzMgMCBvYmoKPDwvVHlwZSAvRXh0R1N0YXRlCi9D QSAxCi9jYSAxCi9CTSAvTm9ybWFsCi9uIDczCi9TQSB0cnVlCj4+CmVuZG9iago3NCAw IG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9FeHRHU3RhdGUKL0NBIDAuMQovY2EgMC4xCi9CTSAvTm9ybWFs Ci9uIDc0Ci9TQSB0cnVlCj4+CmVuZG9iago3NSAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9FeHRHU3Rh dGUKL0NBIDEKL2NhIDEKL0JNIC9Ob3JtYWwKL24gNzUKL1NBIHRydWUKPj4KZW5kb2Jq Cjc2IDAgb2JqCjw8L1R5cGUgL0V4dEdTdGF0ZQovQ0EgMC4xCi9jYSAwLjEKL0JNIC9O b3JtYWwKL24gNzYKL1NBIHRydWUKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjc3IDAgb2JqCjw8L1R5cGUgL0V4 dEdTdGF0ZQovQ0EgMQovY2EgMQovQk0gL05vcm1hbAovbiA3NwovU0EgdHJ1ZQo+Pgpl bmRvYmoKNzggMCBvYmoKPDwvVHlwZSAvRXh0R1N0YXRlCi9DQSAwLjEKL2NhIDAuMQov Qk0gL05vcm1hbAovbiA3OAovU0EgdHJ1ZQo+PgplbmRvYmoKNzkgMCBvYmoKPDwvVHlw ZSAvRXh0R1N0YXRlCi9DQSAxCi9jYSAxCi9CTSAvTm9ybWFsCi9uIDc5Ci9TQSB0cnVl Cj4+CmVuZG9iago4MCAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9FeHRHU3RhdGUKL0NBIDAuMQovY2Eg MC4xCi9CTSAvTm9ybWFsCi9uIDgwCi9TQSB0cnVlCj4+CmVuZG9iago4MSAwIG9iago8 PC9UeXBlIC9FeHRHU3RhdGUKL0NBIDEKL2NhIDEKL0JNIC9Ob3JtYWwKL24gODEKL1NB IHRydWUKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjgyIDAgb2JqCjw8L1R5cGUgL0V4dEdTdGF0ZQovQ0EgMC4x Ci9jYSAwLjEKL0JNIC9Ob3JtYWwKL24gODIKL1NBIHRydWUKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjgzIDAg b2JqCjw8L1R5cGUgL0V4dEdTdGF0ZQovQ0EgMQovY2EgMQovQk0gL05vcm1hbAovbiA4 MwovU0EgdHJ1ZQo+PgplbmRvYmoKODQgMCBvYmoKPDwvVHlwZSAvRXh0R1N0YXRlCi9D QSAwLjEKL2NhIDAuMQovQk0gL05vcm1hbAovbiA4NAovU0EgdHJ1ZQo+PgplbmRvYmoK ODUgMCBvYmoKPDwvVHlwZSAvRXh0R1N0YXRlCi9DQSAxCi9jYSAxCi9CTSAvTm9ybWFs Ci9uIDg1Ci9TQSB0cnVlCj4+CmVuZG9iago4NiAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9FeHRHU3Rh dGUKL0NBIDAuMQovY2EgMC4xCi9CTSAvTm9ybWFsCi9uIDg2Ci9TQSB0cnVlCj4+CmVu ZG9iago4NyAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9FeHRHU3RhdGUKL0NBIDEKL2NhIDEKL0JNIC9O b3JtYWwKL24gODcKL1NBIHRydWUKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjg4IDAgb2JqCjw8L1R5cGUgL0Zv bnQKL0Jhc2VGb250IC9IZWx2ZXRpY2EKL1N1YnR5cGUgL1R5cGUxCi9FbmNvZGluZyAv V2luQW5zaUVuY29kaW5nCj4+CmVuZG9iagoyIDAgb2JqCjw8Ci9Qcm9jU2V0IFsvUERG IC9UZXh0IC9JbWFnZUIgL0ltYWdlQyAvSW1hZ2VJXQovRm9udCA8PAovRjEgODggMCBS Cj4+Ci9YT2JqZWN0IDw8Cj4+Ci9FeHRHU3RhdGUgPDwKL0dTMCA3IDAgUgovR1MxIDgg MCBSCi9HUzIgOSAwIFIKL0dTMyAxMCAwIFIKL0dTNCAxMSAwIFIKL0dTNSAxMiAwIFIK L0dTNiAxMyAwIFIKL0dTNyAxNCAwIFIKL0dTOCAxNSAwIFIKL0dTOSAxNiAwIFIKL0dT MTAgMTcgMCBSCi9HUzExIDE4IDAgUgovR1MxMiAxOSAwIFIKL0dTMTMgMjAgMCBSCi9H UzE0IDIxIDAgUgovR1MxNSAyMiAwIFIKL0dTMTYgMjMgMCBSCi9HUzE3IDI0IDAgUgov R1MxOCAyNSAwIFIKL0dTMTkgMjYgMCBSCi9HUzIwIDI3IDAgUgovR1MyMSAyOCAwIFIK L0dTMjIgMjkgMCBSCi9HUzIzIDMwIDAgUgovR1MyNCAzMSAwIFIKL0dTMjUgMzIgMCBS Ci9HUzI2IDMzIDAgUgovR1MyNyAzNCAwIFIKL0dTMjggMzUgMCBSCi9HUzI5IDM2IDAg UgovR1MzMCAzNyAwIFIKL0dTMzEgMzggMCBSCi9HUzMyIDM5IDAgUgovR1MzMyA0MCAw IFIKL0dTMzQgNDEgMCBSCi9HUzM1IDQyIDAgUgovR1MzNiA0MyAwIFIKL0dTMzcgNDQg MCBSCi9HUzM4IDQ1IDAgUgovR1MzOSA0NiAwIFIKL0dTNDAgNDcgMCBSCi9HUzQxIDQ4 IDAgUgovR1M0MiA0OSAwIFIKL0dTNDMgNTAgMCBSCi9HUzQ0IDUxIDAgUgovR1M0NSA1 MiAwIFIKL0dTNDYgNTMgMCBSCi9HUzQ3IDU0IDAgUgovR1M0OCA1NSAwIFIKL0dTNDkg NTYgMCBSCi9HUzUwIDU3IDAgUgovR1M1MSA1OCAwIFIKL0dTNTIgNTkgMCBSCi9HUzUz IDYwIDAgUgovR1M1NCA2MSAwIFIKL0dTNTUgNjIgMCBSCi9HUzU2IDYzIDAgUgovR1M1 NyA2NCAwIFIKL0dTNTggNjUgMCBSCi9HUzU5IDY2IDAgUgovR1M2MCA2NyAwIFIKL0dT NjEgNjggMCBSCi9HUzYyIDY5IDAgUgovR1M2MyA3MCAwIFIKL0dTNjQgNzEgMCBSCi9H UzY1IDcyIDAgUgovR1M2NiA3MyAwIFIKL0dTNjcgNzQgMCBSCi9HUzY4IDc1IDAgUgov R1M2OSA3NiAwIFIKL0dTNzAgNzcgMCBSCi9HUzcxIDc4IDAgUgovR1M3MiA3OSAwIFIK L0dTNzMgODAgMCBSCi9HUzc0IDgxIDAgUgovR1M3NSA4MiAwIFIKL0dTNzYgODMgMCBS Ci9HUzc3IDg0IDAgUgovR1M3OCA4NSAwIFIKL0dTNzkgODYgMCBSCi9HUzgwIDg3IDAg Ugo+PgovQ29sb3JTcGFjZSA8PAo+PgovUHJvcGVydGllcyA8PC9PQzEgNSAwIFIgL09D MiA2IDAgUj4+Cj4+CmVuZG9iago4OSAwIG9iago8PAovUHJvZHVjZXIgKEFsaXZlUERG IDAuMS41IFJDKQovQ3JlYXRpb25EYXRlIChEOjIwMTUwODEzMTc1MSkKPj4KZW5kb2Jq CjkwIDAgb2JqCjw8Ci9UeXBlIC9DYXRhbG9nCi9QYWdlcyAxIDAgUgovT3BlbkFjdGlv biBbMyAwIFIgL0ZpdEggbnVsbF0KL1BhZ2VMYXlvdXQgL1NpbmdsZVBhZ2UKL1BhZ2VN b2RlIC9Vc2VOb25lCi9PQ1Byb3BlcnRpZXMgPDwvT0NHcyBbNSAwIFIgNiAwIFJdIC9E IDw8L09OIFs1IDAgUl0gL09GRiBbNiAwIFJdIC9BUyBbPDwvRXZlbnQgL1ByaW50IC9P Q0dzIFs1IDAgUiA2IDAgUl0gL0NhdGVnb3J5IFsvUHJpbnRdPj4gPDwvRXZlbnQgL1Zp ZXcgL09DR3MgWzUgMCBSIDYgMCBSXSAvQ2F0ZWdvcnkgWy9WaWV3XT4+XT4+Pj4KPj4K ZW5kb2JqCnhyZWYKMCA5MQowMDAwMDAwMDAwIDY1NTM1IGYgCjAwMDAwMDAwMDkgMDAw MDAgbiAKMDAwMDAxMjcyNSAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDAwMDY0IDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAw MDAxODIgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwNjAyMiAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDA2MTMwIDAwMDAw IG4gCjAwMDAwMDYyMzcgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwNjMxMiAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDA2 MzkxIDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDY0NjYgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwNjU0NyAwMDAwMCBu IAowMDAwMDA2NjI0IDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDY3MDUgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwNjc4 MiAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDA2ODYzIDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDY5NDAgMDAwMDAgbiAK MDAwMDAwNzAyMSAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDA3MDk4IDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDcxNzkg MDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwNzI1NiAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDA3MzM3IDAwMDAwIG4gCjAw MDAwMDc0MTQgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwNzQ5NSAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDA3NTcyIDAw MDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDc2NTMgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwNzczMCAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAw MDA3ODExIDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDc4ODggMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwNzk2OSAwMDAw MCBuIAowMDAwMDA4MDQ2IDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDgxMjcgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAw ODIwNCAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDA4Mjg1IDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDgzNjIgMDAwMDAg biAKMDAwMDAwODQ0MyAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDA4NTIwIDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDg2 MDEgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwODY3OCAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDA4NzU5IDAwMDAwIG4g CjAwMDAwMDg4MzYgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwODkxNyAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDA4OTk0 IDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDkwNzUgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwOTE1MiAwMDAwMCBuIAow MDAwMDA5MjMzIDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDkzMTAgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwOTM5MSAw MDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDA5NDY4IDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDk1NDkgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAw MDAwOTYyNiAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDA5NzA3IDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDk3ODQgMDAw MDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwOTg2NSAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDA5OTQyIDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAw MTAwMjMgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAxMDEwMCAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDEwMTgxIDAwMDAw IG4gCjAwMDAwMTAyNTggMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAxMDMzOSAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDEw NDE2IDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMTA0OTcgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAxMDU3NCAwMDAwMCBu IAowMDAwMDEwNjU1IDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMTA3MzIgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAxMDgx MyAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDEwODkwIDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMTA5NzEgMDAwMDAgbiAK MDAwMDAxMTA0OCAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDExMTI5IDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMTEyMDYg MDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAxMTI4NyAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDExMzY0IDAwMDAwIG4gCjAw MDAwMTE0NDUgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAxMTUyMiAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDExNjAzIDAw MDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMTE2ODAgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAxMTc2MSAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAw MDExODM4IDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMTE5MTkgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAxMTk5NiAwMDAw MCBuIAowMDAwMDEyMDc3IDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMTIxNTQgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAx MjIzNSAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDEyMzEyIDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMTIzOTMgMDAwMDAg biAKMDAwMDAxMjQ3MCAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDEyNTUxIDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMTI2 MjggMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAxMzk0MyAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDE0MDI2IDAwMDAwIG4g CnRyYWlsZXIKPDwKL1NpemUgOTEKL1Jvb3QgOTAgMCBSCi9JbmZvIDg5IDAgUgo+Pgpz dGFydHhyZWYKMTQzMzgKJSVFT0YK
```

Please help me.

Comment: I practically broke my mouse wheel scrolling to the bottom of your question.

Comment: You should not dump everything in question.Better to create small example to clarify your problem.

Comment: If I understand that long question ... you are trying to add a base 64 encoded string into a paragraph in a PDF. Why? So you can have a PDF that consists the acsii data? That makes no sense.

Comment: I think you want to encrypt the pdf file ?If yes.This is not the way.Simply you can get the `byte stream` of your file and change that `byte stream` with any byte changing pattern.Let say every byte + 1 and then write the file.again you want to read the file do above task reversely.

Comment: @Jimmer  
I created a webservice from which i get base64 converted file from mobile device .I want to convert this to original file and store it on server

Comment: If you convert base64 do it revers again to get back original file.What's that code you used to convert file into base64 as a webservice?

Comment: @Ace Base64 is not the way to do your task.Try something like this.

http://www.codejava.net/coding/file-encryption-and-decryption-simple-example
-
http://stackoverflow.com/q/27962116/1641556

Comment: @Jimmer Actually mobile user pick a file and send it to server.So question is how to store it on server.For this mobile device convert it into base64 ,send it at back end side using webservice .then we convert this to original file and store it

Comment: @Ace why do you convert the files to store ? are you store file in database ?

Comment: No . on server and accessing it from server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Base64-Byte-Array is already a PDF (it starts with the [magic-number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29)  for PDF-Files `%PDF`), you can write the decoded Bytes directly to a File and have your PDF.

```
try(OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("filename.pdf")){
    out.write(decodedBytes );
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution.Pdf get created but when I open this document it gives message "Failed to load pdf document"

Comment: Your Input (without the Blanks) convertet to a byte[] via `java.util.Base64.Decoder.decode(String)` and written out with the Code above works for me (some PDF with Trucking Management)

Comment: I am using java6.Because of this am i getting problem?

Comment: Might be. What Base64 Implementation do you use?

Comment: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;                                         byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(encodedstr);

Answer (score 0):

The `decodedBytes` is the PDF binary data. You can't convert that to a `String`.

Comment: So how to get Base64 converted pdf to original pdf?

Comment: Base64 doesn't know anything about PDF. You convert (encode) binary data (e.g. a PDF file) to Base64, which looks like text, send that to where it needs to be, where it gets converted (decoded) back to binary data. If the source was a PDF, then end result is a PDF.

Comment: I created a webservice from which i get base64 converted file .I want to convert this to original file and store it on server

Comment: So store the `decodedBytes`. No need for a `PdfWriter`. The bytes *are* the PDF.