# AES Encryption/decryption Java

Tags: java

How can I create an encryption/decryption app for java? I know there a lot of guides, but I would like to know the process behind the code as well. I a looking towards AES.

Also, can the key remain the same so that  multiple devices can translate the same secret into the same normal language?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AES Encryption and Decryption with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796042/aes-encryption-and-decryption-with-java)

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard